# What is the best place to put view function?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, recursion

I have a hierarchical array:

```
array(
  'id' => 4, //id of current element
  'parent' => 2, //id of parent element
  'value' => '', //some value
  'children' => array() //array of similar arrays
)
```

Each element can contain a number of elements, which can contain a number of elements etc. Suffice to say, best way to iterate over this is to use function, which will call itself to process children:

```
function print_menu_hierarchy($hierarchy, $depth = 0) {
    foreach ($hierarchy as $item) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '    <td>' . $item['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '    <td>' . str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 6) .  $item['value'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        if (count($item['children'])) {
            print_menu_hierarchy($item['children'], $depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is: where to put that function?

To maintain MVC, it has to be part of view. So, either helper or template.

Helper would be obvious, but putting this function to helper would make it harder to modify view. Each time I would change something in template, I'd have to change helper as well. Besides, this function grows larger and larger, and keeping it clean is hard.

Template is bad choice as well, defining functions should be done somewhere else.

Anyone have better idea where to put this?

(I'm using symfony 1.4)

Comment: I'd expect that helpers should only somehow modify data for output or other processing. Your function is creating an HTML structure for output, so I'd put it to the view template maybe... By this You'd only edit a template and maintain changes only at one place...

Comment: Sounds like a great example of the pattern leading the programmer. Use design patterns to make your life easier and enable you to write more agile code, not to constrain you and stop you from being expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not clear for me what framework you're using, the function itself - as you said it yourself - does not belong to the view. This function should be put in the helper part of your application. The only change you'd need to make is to call the view for a single item from this helper function, instead of hard-coding the echos into your hierarchy crawler. Something like this:

```
function print_menu_hierarchy($hierarchy, $depth = 0) {
    foreach ($hierarchy as $item) {
        call_view_function('view_name_for_menu_item', array('item' => $item, 'depth' => $depth));
        if (count($item['children'])) {
            print_menu_hierarchy($item['children'], $depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And the view would look like:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $params['item']['id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', $params['depth'] * 6) . $params['item']['value']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm using symfony 1.4.
I thought of doing something similar:
include_partial('view_name_for_menu_item', array('item' => $item, 'depth' => $depth))
but this would mean a lot inclusions.

Comment: Well I don't know Symphony, but I assume it has some convenient way to auto-resolve view inclusions. Anyways, I think this is the clean approach for solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it a helper. It's inevitable that you're going to have to modify it when you change the template. If it's a large function, a helper is the best place. This means it can also be used in different places.

Also, MVC is there to help you. It's a guide. Don't let it block you in getting the job done. Every moment you're agonizing over where to put things is a moment you're not actually solving a problem.

Comment: In the same moment you are coming closer to solving the problem in the best way possible.

Comment: Most definitely. But we have to always keep an eye on getting the job done.

Comment: @Tomalak Certainly. I just meant that these patterns are there to help us and not hinder us